# Using x86 rastertolilo on raspberry pi via qemu using x86 docker container

Tags: emulation, docker, pi-5, cups

I have a raspberry pi 5 and and old laser printer (ricoh sp211). I want to run cups to make this usb printer available through the whole network. The problem is, the driver, or rather the filter file (rastertolilo) is for x86 systems... making every print result in a filter error, logically.

I found a blog where someone with the same printer somehow made it work using a crazy solution: He has cups running on an orange pi zero. he replaced the content of the rastertolilo file with a bash so whenever a print is made and the file is called it starts a qemu powered docker container with an x86 ubuntu which contains the file (rastertolilo) and execute only this file in a x86 environment. crazy

Unluckily I'm unskilled with qemu and docker and especially the combination of the both so I struggle to replicate his solution. I tried feeding the blog to chatGPT but at least the 3.5/4 isn't helping at all.

https://medium.com/@amit.sharma.hyd/transforming-my-wired-printer-to-wireless-229a36e3414c

this is the blog.

I believe its only a few calls in terminal but as I'm too stupid I'm asking if someone has ever done something similar and maybe has a more explicit tutorial.